# How to use %username% wildcard in paths for IO functions

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, directory

I would like to have a folder which contains a folder for each user accessing it.

C:\bla\blabla\user1
C:\bla\blabla\user2
etc

How can I use the Windows %username% wildcard to do this in .NET?

This, for example:

`IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\bla\blabla\%username%")`

Just gives me a folder called exactly "C:\bla\blabla\%username%\"

Comment: Add code which finds these `%stuff%` placeholders, extracts the `stuff`, feeds it through [`Environment.GetEnvironmentalVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-5.0), and inserts the resolved value, with appropriate error-handling. You can do that with e.g. `Regex.Replace(input, @"%(\w+)%", m => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(m.Groups[1].Value))`

Comment: Open cmd.exe and type > Set which give a list of environmental variables.  The get variable using something like this : string username = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("username");

Comment: Wouldn't it better to store this data in a folder under each user's AppData? The a) the data is private to each user and becomes part of their profile, and b) you can get to it simply via %AppData%\yourappname. That's how most applications do this kind of thing, if you notice, and it's what MS recommends for per-user data. They might also create a folder under the user's Documents folder, for stuff related to the app which the user might actually want to look at and find (whereas AppData is generally for settings and that kind of thing.)

Comment: @ADyson Normally yes, in this case they just happen to need a folder each in a shared location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%username%` is an environment variable in Windows that returns the current user's username.

VB.NET provides us with property that does the same thing, Environment.UserName: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username

Here is an example using it along with Path.Combine: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine

```vb
IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(IO.Path.Combine("C:\bla\blabla", Environment.UserName))
```

Answer (score 0):

Different ways

```
    Dim userNM As String = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name
    userNM = userNM.Substring(userNM.IndexOf("\"c) + 1) 'remove domain

    userNM = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("username")

    userNM = Environment.UserName

    userNM = My.User.Name
    userNM = userNM.Substring(userNM.IndexOf("\"c) + 1) 'remove domain
```